# How to compile/link ratfor code by gfortran compiler?

Tags: linux, gfortran

I've installed gfortran on my ubuntu 20x (amd-64) to learn programming from a very famous book, *Software Tools* by Kernighan & Plauger, and the language they used was ratfor so could you please tell me if it's possible to compile the example code (written in ratfor) on gfortran. If it's possible, what are the essential parameter/flags/switches for compiling and linking?
I've got a moderate knowledge on C but I never used fortran. I don't know how to build fortran code.

Thank you.

P.S Any reference to books/links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compile Ratfor using gfortran. Ratfor is a different language, it is not Fortran. You have to find a preprocessor that translates Ratfor into Fortran or into some other language.

A quick google finds http://sepwww.stanford.edu/doku.php?id=sep:software:ratfor90 but there may be better things around and this site is not for software recommendations.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just come to know about it. I've just downloaded the C src for ratfor77 from http://sepwww.stanford.edu/doku.php?id=sep:software:ratfor and build it after I heavily modified Makefile. This comes with two .r test files. As I stated in my post, I want to compile and build the codes from the aforementioned books. Any help? Thanks again.

Comment: @Bishnu Sorry, I do not know anything about that software, you will have to follow the instructions from the site.

Comment: Ok. It's all right. Thanks again. Wishing you a happy 'n auspicious Bijaya Dashami.